# Проверка записи на совпадение

Tags: sql, javascript, php, mysql

Как сделать проверку записи на совпадение, перед добавлением ее в базу данных ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT link_site FROM link WHERE link_site ='$les'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
{

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO link(link_site) VALUES ('$les')",$db);
}
else
{
echo 'уже есть такая запись';
}
```

Comment: Данный пример не совсем рабочий. У меня срабатывает(добавляет запись в БД) он только один раз, потом все время вылетает сообщение "уже есть такая запись" Что это может быть ???

Answer (score 2):

Можно поставить в таблице тип поля PRIMARY с которым делается проверка на совпадение. Повтора не будет, т.е если значение поля повторное, запрос не будет выполнен. А если запрос не будет выполнен можете вывести ошибку, что переданные данные повторные.

Answer (score 2):

Типа такого... Можете искать в Гугле

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from table_name where '$name' = pole_name");
$row = fetch_array($query);
```

Comment: У вас случайно не допущенная ошибка? Вместо mysql_fetch_array, у Вас fetch_array. Плюс мы делаем так лишний запрос в БД. Если реализовать таким методом, я рекомендовал бы в запросе `select * from table_name where '$name' = pole_name`, заместь * написать одно поле.

Comment: Пример кода: `$a = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT 'pole_name' FROM 'table' WHERE 'pole_name'='".$name."' LIMIT 1"));  IF(isset($a['pole_name'])) echo 'Повтор'; else echo 'Уникальная запись';`